# findding the position of elements with iterator

Tags: c++, vector

How can I find the index of an element in a vector? Assume a snapshot of the vector contains

```
10 12 15 23 43
```

Now I want to insert a number.

1- insert 15 => return 2 (the position)

2- insert 50 => push_back() => return 5 (the position)

This is what I wrote however the I can not convert iterator to integer.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

vector<int> v;
int insertVector(int a);
int main()
{
   int a;
   cout << "enter number: ";
   cin >> a;
   int pos = insertVector(a);
   cout << pos;   // update
   return 0;    
}

int insertVector(int a)
{
   vector<int>::iterator it;
   it = find(v.begin(), v.end(), a);
   if (it == v.end()) {
      v.push_back(a);
      return v.size();
   }
   return it;   // error
}
```

UPDATE:

If I change `return it;` to `return *it;`, the output is wrong. Like this:

```
enter number: 10
1
enter number: 20 
2
enter number: 25
3
enter number: 35
4
enter number: 45  
5
enter number: 5
6
enter number: 25
25   // wrong
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`insertVector`'s return type is `int`, but you may return an iterator. Change your code to:

```
int insertVector(int a)
{
   vector<int>::iterator it;
   vector<int>::iterator begin = v.begin();
   it = find(begin, v.end(), a);
   if (it == v.end()) {
      v.push_back(a);
      return v.size();
   }
   return std::distance(begin, it);
}
```

Comment: Yeah I know. How can I resolve that. I want the numbers as stated in the example

Answer (score 1):

You can explicitly iterate the vector yourself : (less elegant but requires one iteration over the vector)

```
int position = 0;
for (it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it; ++position) {
     if (*it == a) {
         return position; 
     }
}

v.push_back(a);
return v.size() - 1;
```

Comment: Yeah I know that. I wanted to use `find` from `algorithm`. That will reduce the code lines. If there is no another way, I will iterate manually

Comment: so why not do it ? as you can see there is no much magic in iterators so either you write a more sophisticated iterator implementation or just use a simple O(n) iteration.